# How to use restful upload multiple files with array?

Tags: python, file-upload, eve

my schema:

```
test_multivalues = {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'multi': {'type': 'list', 'schema': {'type': 'media'}},
    'arr': {'type': 'list'},
}
```

I use the post data as follow:

Content-Type: multipart/form-data

```
name: multivalue
multi: ....file1...
multi: ....file2....
arr: [arr_value1, arr_value2]
```

In Eve,parameter `arr` will get as a list, but `multi` only get the first value. 
I expect to get `multi` as a list like [file1, file2].

When I read the code, Eve use werkzeug's `MultiDict.to_dict()` in `payload()` method which only return the first value for the same key.
How can I get the key with multiple values as list ?

**Updated:**
Eve will raise an exception with above schema and post data: 
`multi:must be of list type`

**Updated：**
Yes, I test it with curl.

```
curl -F "image=@text.txt" -F "image=@test.txt"  http://localhost/eve/api
```

When I changed the code in payload() to：

```
v = lambda l: l if len(l) > 1 else l[0]
return dict([(k, v(request.form.getlist(k))) for k in request.form] +
            [(k, v(request.files.getlist(k))) for k in request.files])
```

it return file list, but Eve's post method not support it, and throw an exception.

Comment: I think the problem here is that werkzeug is parsing each `multi` as an independent field, and not as an array. Can you update the post with the complete request example? I assume it's curl?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly way to solve this:

```
def saver(filestorageobj):
    app.media.put(
                filestorageobj,
                filename=filestorageobj.name,
                content_type=filestorageobj.mimetype,
                resource='test')

def pre_test_POST_callback(request):
    from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict

    # files format: [("pics", FileStorageObject)]
    pics = [saver(
        upfile[1]
        ) for upfile in request.files.items(True) if upfile[0] == "pics"]
    form = request.form.copy()
    form['pics'] = pics
    request.form = ImmutableMultiDict(form)
    request.files = ImmutableMultiDict()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 0.7+ version of eve, you only need to set AUTO_COLLAPSE_MULTI_KEYS to True.